# How can i sum the value of a datagridview by username

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Username label which is passed in from the username login.  on one of the win forms i have a datagridview and one of the columns stores numbers in decimal(3,1).
I have a for loop which goes through all the numbers and sums up the numbers.  But what i am looking to do is only sum up the numbers based on the username login which is passed as a username_lbl to this winform.  can this be done within a for loop

I have tried a for loop which sums up all users. but i am unsure how to sum based on the username.

```
public Mileage(string Username)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Username_Mileage_lbl.Text = Username;
 } 

private void Total_Miles_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Mileage_dataGridView.Rows.Count; ++i )
    {
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(Mileage_dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
    }
    MessageBox.Show(sum.ToString());
}
```

I am expecting The username has a total of 100, but instead it displays all of the users total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the loop you could compare the username of the row with the username in the label, and only if they match add to sum.
Suppose the username is in the 5th cell in your datagridview, then use this

```
private void Total_Miles_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Mileage_dataGridView.Rows.Count; ++i )
    {
        if (Username_Mileage_lbl.Text == Mileage_dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString())
        {
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(Mileage_dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show(sum.ToString());
}
```

You might need to do some more checks and stuff, like `ToLower` if the case don't always match for example.